# selenium elementIdElement functionality

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, nightwatch.js

The documentation on code.google.com describes the elementIdElement functionality as "Search for an element on the page, starting from the identified element". Does this mean the search is done for every element following that element throughout the rest of the web page or only for dependents of that element?

If it is the former, then how would I construct the "value" entry if the "using" parameter is "css selector" and I want to find a descendant of the current element's sibling? I thought the value would be "+ div .classname", but this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do it is by emulating Selenium ByChained, by calling one wait after another:

```
browser
  .useXpath()
  .url('http://www.google.com')
  .waitForElementVisible('.//body', 1000)
  .waitForElementVisible(".//div[contains(@class, 'classVar')]")
  .click('button')
```

Comment: Not sure what language/environment your example shows, but it doesn't look like anything I've seen. To clarify, my coding environment is javascript using selenium and nightwatchjs.

Comment: @BrynWolfe - You are correct.  By default, Nightwatch does not have `expect.element`  that accepts 2 arguments for a ByChained locator.   Probably something that could be added though.  I added the `nightwatch` tag to your question.

Comment: I have no experience with `nightwatch.js`  but I updated my question to attempt an answer.

Comment: Thanks for adding my question to nightwatch. I couldn't figure out how to do that. As for your modified code example, I don't see how that addresses my question. Assume I call browser.element to get an  ELEMENT number. Using that element reference, I now want to go to its parent and find that parent's sibling to see if it contains an element of the same class as the original ELEMENT. I can use elementIdElement to go to the parent using an xpath selector ("..") but from there I'm not clear on what would get me to the desired element.

Comment: The first .waitFor...  gets you to the parent (as long as you use the ../ notation on a xpath)  then the second .waitFor gets the element relative from that element.

Comment: Lets call the current element E. The first xpath '..' gets me to the parent of E, but that second xpath just finds E again. I need to find another element with the same class as E but residing in the parent's sibling. That's the xpath syntax that eludes me.

Comment: That sounds exactly as I described.  You can also do it as a single XPath locator.  Something like `By.xpath(".//div[class='blah']/../..//div[contains(@class,'blah')]")` .  The possibilities are endless.  Does that make sense? Note: see the double slash wildcard I added.  Use Firefox Firepath and you can figure anything out.  There should be no question.

Answer (score 0):

The correct xpath string for navigating to an element's parent's following sibling for the existence of another element with a given class is

'(//div[@id="currentElementID"]/../following-sibling::*[1]//div[contains(@class,"classToLookFor")])[1]'

In this example, I know the current element's ID so that's what I use, but the '//div[@id="currentElementID"]' can be replaced with whatever you need to navigate to the starting element. Also, this example assumes the element I'm looking for is a div.

Comment: @djangofan This "solution" only works with an absolute path and the nightwatch call to selenium's browser.element method. Each iteration that fails to match using the above xpath would insert another "../" to the "/../" part of the string. However, as the path gets longer with each iteration, it takes successively longer. I'd like to use the elementIdElement to start from the current element instead of an absolute path, but can't figure out the syntax. Unfortunately, Firepath doesn't seem to support the notion of "current element", e.g., typing "." goes to <document>, not the current element.

Comment: Nevermind. I was misunderstanding the somewhat cryptic error message I got from nightwatch/selenium that lead me to believe the relative xpath selector wasn't working when in fact it was a missing parameter to elementIdElement. The relative xpath string is exactly what I thought it should be, i.e., '(../following-sibling::*[1]//div[contains(@class,"classToLookFor")])[1]'